# How to ask if a dropped object belongs to someone?

Tags: second-person-pronouns

Let's say I see a wallet on the ground and a person I suspect dropped it. In English I would naturally ask" Excuse me. Is this your wallet?" A direct Japanese translation would be"すみませんあなたの財布ですか" but time and time again I hear that using "あなた" is rude. How then do I get around this in case the person a complete stranger?

Comment: So are you just asking about directness/rudeness of あなた, or are you really asking about a dropped wallet?

Comment: @istrasci I want to know how to ask a stranger in a polite way if he dropped the wallet I found on the ground. I'd normally ask "is this your wallet?" but since the " あなた" is considered something rude to tell a stranger, what's the alternative?

Comment: Honestly, あなた is not *that* rude here, though it of course doesn’t hurt to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask without あなた (Avoid direct translation).

Japanese expressions will work without the pronoun in one-to-one conversations. If I actually saw a person dropped a wallet, then I would reach the person and say in statement form:

> あの、すみません、財布おとしましたよ。
>   Um, excuse me. [You] dropped [a/your] wallet.

Then again, if I *suspect* the person dropped a wallet, or if I am not sure who dropped it, then I would reach whomever I saw near by and say in question form:

> あの、すみません、財布おとしましたか？
>   Um, excuse me. Did [you] drop [a/your] wallet?

No need for the pronoun, use either the statement form or the question form.